# ng2-pdf-viewer latest version (6.3.2) is not working at 60.0.312 version of chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, pdf, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I am trying to use the latest version of [ng2-pdf-viewer(6.3.2)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer/v/4.1.2#stick-to-page) component to display PDFs at chrome 60.0.312 version, but it is not displaying the PDF and I don't get any error at console. The same ng2-pdf-viewer version works fine at the latest version of chrome (87.0.4280.88).

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer'; // <- import PdfViewerModule

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    PdfViewerModule // <- Add PdfViewerModule to imports
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  src = "https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf";
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h2>PDF Viewer</h2>

<div class="pdf-container">
  <pdf-viewer [src]="src" [original-size]="false" style="display:block; height:840px;"></pdf-viewer>
</div>
```

**Please let me know:**

- if I am missing any essentials.
- Is there any possible way to use latest version of ng2-pdf-viewer(6.3.2) at chrome (60.0.312).